# Sorting by strings

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement quick sort to sort a list of string values that are all numeric.

it looks like `["1","2","3","4","5"]` and so on

I'm using the following code to compare elements

```
public class TypeComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> {
    @Override
    public int compare(E a, E b) {
        return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

My sorted list, however returns values in this order

```
First 5:
1 10 100 1000 10000 
Last 5:
99995 99996 99997 99998 99999
```

The first 5 values are obviously wrong, and the last 5 values should be 99996-100000

With integer values the sort works correctly, but with strings I believe I'm not comparing them correctly.

Comment: Why do you use a String to hold integers in the first place?

Comment: Gotta compared them by their numeric value with a Long.valueOf or Integer.valueOf (depending on the max size) else as String they are compared alphabeticly and thus if it start by a 1 it's always before a number starting by a 9

Comment: Also, note that your Comparator is not safe, and is equivalent to Comparator.naturalOrder(). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--

Comment: You have successfully sorted in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: @JBNizet part of my instructions are to sort the same list with two data types, one being integers, and the other being strings.

Comment: @Ozymandias well, lexicographic order is correct for `String` but obviously not for `int`. You need to learn about generics.

Comment: P.S. [friend of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829222/java-generic-array-sorting-with-comparator#comment86673892_49829222)?

Comment: And you've done that successfully. Strings are being sorted, using their natural, lexicographic order. You should thus not expect strings to be sorted in ascending order of their numeric value because, for a start, most strings don't represent numbers.

Comment: @JBNizet "_most strings don't represent numbers_" [citation needed] ;)

Comment: If you want to feel more comfortable, use "00001" instead of "1" (and do the same for all the other values, of course) in your tests with strings.

Comment: @BoristheSpider may very well be a classmate of mine haha.

JBNizet understood. I suppose I then need to cast the generic into an integer then?

Comment: @Ozymandias nooo. Except for the comparator implementation, the result you get is absolutely correct. What is incorrect is your expectation that "10" should be bigger than "2".

Comment: Feel free to do that and see the outcome, then try and work out why it happened.

Comment: @JBNizet I may be wrong, but I believe I'm expected to sort both values in ascending order as if numerically.

I haven't considered that I may need to allow it to sort lexicographically. I'll ask my professor.

Comment: The sorting algorithm shouldn't care about that. It's the role of the Comparator to decide how the elements should be compared. If you want the strings to be compared in a numeric order rather than a lexicographic order, then pass another comparator implementation when sorting.

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "10", "5"));
    strings.sort(Comparator.comparing(Integer::parseInt));
```

Possible will be faster for big arrays

```
    List<String> sorted = strings.stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sorted()
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement a comparator for `Integer` class. `Integer` class already implements `Comparable` interface and has `compareTo` method. That means you can sort classes like Integer, Long, BigDecimal using only TreeSet:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "10", "5"));
Set<Integer> sorted = new TreeSet<>();
for(String s : strings) {
   sorted.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
sorted.forEach(el -> System.out.println(el));
```

That solution is not really what you're after, as it returns a collection of sorted Integers not Strings, but worth to keep that in mind in the future.